# Что происходит с сообщениями при наследование от другого класса

Tags: java, spring

Например, я наследуюсь от какого-то класса, у которого уже есть 4-5 наследников.
И вот, я перезаписываю метод этого класса.
Что происходит с сообщением/ошибкой, которая возникает в рамках суперкласса? Она направляется на всех потомков и там обрабатывается, но так как я использую свой собственный подкласс, то я вижу результат выполнения только у него?

Например,

```
class Super {

    String sendMessage(String message, boolean send){
    // bla-bla
    }

}

class One extends Super {

    @Override
    String sendMessage(String message, boolean send){
    // bla-bla
    }

}
```

1) И таких потомков, да пусть хоть 10 штук. В итоге, получится что где-то и как-то вызывается мой `Super`, допустим это сторонняя библиотека и, этот Super смотрит, есть ли у него потомки, если есть, то передает `message, send` им, если нет, то обрабатывает всё сам ?

2) Интересно еще то, что в каких случаях я должен прям писать внутри метода потока, что-то в виде

```
    @Override
    String sendMessage(String message, boolean send){
        super.sendMessage(message,send);  // Вот эту строчку, а потом лишь свой обработчик
    // bla-bla
    }
```

А в каких я могу опустить `super...`

3)Можно ли для всех потомков ( если они мои и родительский класс тоже мой) сделать так, чтобы, если `send` = false, то ниодин потомок не обрабатывал `sendMessage`? А именно, что-то типо

```
    class Super {

        String sendMessage(String message, boolean send){
            if(!send){ return "No message";}
            // bla-bla
       }

}
```

Comment: А зачем вам отправлять message для всех потомков? Вы переопределили метод родителя для определенного потомка и данный метод будет действовать лишь для него.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Super ничего не знает о своих потомках.

Для реализации наследования используется таблица виртуальных методов.

Я не уверен, как в деталях она сделана в Java машине, но условно работает так:

Для вашего класса Super в памяти есть таблица, которая содержит в себе идентификатор метода и ссылку на его реализацию.

Для каждого наследника есть такая же таблица, в ней есть сслыка на таблицу Super и информация о всех переопределенных методах.
Когда вы исполняете следующий код:

```
Super myEntity = new One();
myEntity.sendMessage("Blah-Blah", true);
```

В момент исполнения Java машина проверяет, какой на самом деле тип у значения в переменной myEntity. Это оказывается One. Затем она идет в таблицу для этого типа и вызывает код соответствующий переопределенному методу sendMessage из класса One.

Ваш код super.sendMessage(...) всего лишь заставляет java машину в этой точке вызывать аналогичный метод из родительской таблицы и после его завершения продолжить исполнение текущего кода. Соответственно вызов super... нужен если вы хотите выполнить логику из родительского класса, а если это не требуется, вызывать его не нужно.

Как вариант для решения вопроса:

> 3)Можно ли для всех потомков ( если они мои и родительский класс тоже
>   мой) сделать так, чтобы, если send = false, то ниодин потомок не
>   обрабатывал sendMessage? А именно, что-то типо

можете разделить ваш метод на 2.

```
final String sendMessage(String message, boolean send){
            if(!send){ return "No message";}
            return sendMessage(message)
       }
String sendMessage(String message){
            //Blah, Blah
       }
```

Ну а в потомках переопределяйте sendMessage с одним параметром.